# % (examples in loop)

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

```
% (examples in loop)
```

i don't know what is the purpose of % in loop why to % in loop

please give one or two basic example % using loop and also define % in loop

Thank you

Comment: I tried to understand what you're asking, but I still have no idea. Could you clarify the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One particular use is to check even / odd:

```
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
{
    if($i%2==0)
    echo "even"
    else
    echo "odd"
}
```

This idea could be used to color rows (tr) of a table differently for better presentation.

---

Another use is to close TR dynamically in a complex code (lets say, change tr after every 4 tds). Like:

```
echo "<tr>";
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
{
    if($i%4==0)
    echo "</tr><tr>";

    echo "<td>";
    .
    .
    .
    echo "</td>";

}
echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 3):

The `%` is simply a [Modulus Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).

It serves no difference inside or outside a loop. It is simply an arithmetic operator that returns the remainder of a division.